# Migrate: how to get uid from MigrateUser

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm using migrate module, but I don't understand how to get "uid" from my "MigrateMhtAuthor" class (it is sourceMigration setting). I have this code in my main class:

```
class MigrateMhtAdsMigration extends DynamicMigration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    [...]
    $uid_mapping = $this->addFieldMapping("uid","utente")->sourceMigration('MigrateMhtAuthor');
    [...]
  }
}
```

I know that MigrateMhtAuthor works because I have imported my user with this migrate class.

I have create some "debug" point in the MigrateMhtAuthor class and this is the output when I import/migrate a node:

```
MigrateMhtAuthorMigration __construct
MhtAuthorDestination __construct
MigrateMhtAuthorMigration fine
```

[MhtAuthorDestination is a class that make the real insert. It search if the user exist (based on email check) to prevent the double email error]

So, I can see that the  MigrateMhtAuthor is call, but when I go to see the uid of the node that I have just imported/migrate I see "1" (uid = 1).

Where is my error ? If you want to see my classes can I insert a link to pastebin?

EDIT:

I have found a way, but I don't understand why in this way works.

The new code is:

```
class MigrateMhtAdsMigration extends DynamicMigration {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    [...]
    $uid_mapping = $this->addFieldMapping("uid","uid2");
    [...]
  }

  public function prepareRow($content_row) {
    [....]
     $current_row->uid2 = $this->handleSourceMigration('MigrateMhtAuthor',$current_row->id);
    [....]
  }
}
```

So, I don't understand what "sourceMigration()" mean if I need to use "handleSourceMigration" in prepareRow() function.